# How to calculate the sum of a series with the nth term being user input in Java

Tags: java, sum, series

I am trying to compute a summation and Pi. I have gotten the Pi calculation to work, but am having difficulty on the summation. The output of the summation is supposed to calculate 1/3 + 3/5 + 5/7 .... a number/n the nth term is the user input, but I am uncertain about my calculation. If I input 5 the output should calculate 1/3 + 3/5, but this code would add 5 terms 1/3 + 3/5 + 5/7 + 7/9 + 9/11, what am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class n01092281
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your nth term for the series.");
      double userInput = input.nextInt();   
      double sum = 0.0;
      for(int i = 2; i <= userInput*2; i+=2) {
         sum += ((double)(i-1)/(i+1));
       }
      System.out.printf("The sum of the series is %12.12f" , sum); 
      double Pi = 0;
      for (int counter = 1; counter < userInput; counter++){
         Pi += 4 * (Math.pow(-1,counter + 1)/((2*counter) - 1));
      }
      System.out.printf(" ,The computation of Pi is %1.12f",  Pi);
   }   
}
```

Comment: According to your code, suppose user gives `n = 4` your loop goes up to `1/3 + 3/5 + 5/7 + 7/9`. But according to your  explanation of the summation, it should stop at `1/3 + 3/5`.  Remove  `i <= userInput*2;` and place `i <= userInput;` only.

Comment: @fgdark did you tried my solution ?

Comment: When I input 3 it gives .400000000 and 5 is close but is at .971428571429

Comment: @fgdark Are you still looking for the answer ? Are you sure that 3 gives 0.4000 ? check this link out [Demo Link](https://ideone.com/P2YNg1)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you are doing the right calculation. I just changed the way you were using i. Also you just need to update the count how many times exactly you would like to go.

This is how I changed it

```
      double userInput = 11;
      int count =0;
      if(userInput>=3){
          count =(int)( userInput-1)/2;
      }
      double sum = 0.0;
      for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
         sum += ((double)(2*i-1)/(2*i+1));
         System.out.print((2*i-1)+"/"+(2*i+1)+' ');
       }
      System.out.println();
      System.out.printf("The sum of the series is %12.12f" , sum);
```

Output:-

```
1/3 3/5 5/7 7/9 9/11 
The sum of the series is 3.243578643579
```

Here I am also printing series, to make clear for you.

Comment: If I input 2 it gives me the 1/3 + 3/5, but what if I wanted the nth term to be the denominator so if I put in 5 it would give me the 1/3 +3/5... 5 being the denominator of the last term

Comment: @fgdark. check my solution again. Hope it  works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question your series is r/n where n is the nth term. Use this simple function to sum the series up to nth term.

```
private static void sum_up_series(int nth) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nth; i++) {
        int r = (1 + (i * 2));
        int n = (3 + (i * 2));
        if (n <= nth) {
            sum += (double) (r) / (n);
            System.out.print(r + "/" + n + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\nsum = " + sum);
}
```

here is the output of n= 11

```
1/3 3/5 5/7 7/9 9/11 sum = 3.2435786435786436
```